# How to install TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API on Apple Silicon (ARM/M1)

Tags: python-3.x, api, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

I have already installed TensorFlow 2. But I am having trouble with TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API installation in my Macbook Pro M1. I need a little bit of help. If you know how to solve this, let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.